# App is running but does not fetch data from json

Tags: java, android, json

I am learning json and not getting solution.

I have tried updating my json file and xml file but no working.

here is the code

the errors I have faced in the code is written

below
please help me through it.

The app is running perfectly but does not fetch data from this link below
https://api.myjson.com/bins/1hkm17

```
package com.taxsmart.jsonsimpleexample;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.taxsmart.jsonsimpleexample.MainActivity;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data ="";
    String dataParsed = "";
    String singleParsed ="";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1hkm17");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i =0 ;i <JA.length(); i++){
                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                singleParsed =  "Name" + JO.get("name") + "\n"+
                                "Password" + JO.get("Password") + "\n"+
                                "Contact" + JO.get("Contact") + "\n"+
                                "Country" + JO.get("Country") + "\n";

                dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed +"\n" ;

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        MainActivity.data.setText(this.dataParsed);

    }
}
```

The errors are here

```
I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
[CDS]rx timeout:0
[OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for Name
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at 
com.taxsmart.jsonsimpleexample.fetchData.doInBackground
(fetchData.java:38)at 
 com.taxsmart.jsonsimpleexample.fetchData.doInBackground
 (fetchData.java:18)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at 
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
  (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: You probably want to add in a newline in `data = data + line;`

Comment: You can confirm this by printing out the `data` value after it has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my error I had written wrong code on my json file so it was not loading the code